# 'not spam' email is not recognised as such in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I have a long time, private (not corporate) Gmail account.
In the last few months, almost all new incoming mail ends up in the spam folder, even though I keep marking it as 'not spam'.

Any suggestions on how to let Gmail know that bona fide messages are not spam?

Comment: Sometimes it's a matter of persistence. I have had the issue with mails from the BackupWordpress plugin, and I kept flagging them as 'not spam' for weeks. Maybe other users were doing the same, I don't know. Is there something common with the *almost all new incoming mail*?

Comment: Do these emails follow any pattern? Are they sent as part of an alias or campaign, or are they direct (user to user)?

Comment: AFAICD, there's no pattern: some mails are from lists I registered to receive new updates from, and some are from family. @OnenOnlyWalter

Answer (score 3):

When that happened to me, I created a new [filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579).

And I've defined that every message that comes to my email - "Never send it to Spam".

[image]

You can also set only certain addresses, and more ...